# javascript add key to array value lat and lng for google map latlng

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array that look like these: these are coordinates from an API

```
const paths = [
  [22.372081, 114.107877],
  [22.326442, 114.167811],
  [22.284419, 114.159510]
];
```

I need to convert it to something like these: with keys of lat and lng for each row.

```
{lat: 22.372081, lng: 114.107877},
{lat: 22.326442, lng: 114.167811},
{lat: 22.284419, lng: 114.159510}
```

I only have this short code but its not working what i wanted.

```
const waypts= [];
const paths = [
  [22.372081, 114.107877],
  [22.326442, 114.167811],
  [22.284419, 114.159510]
];
for(let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
  waypts.push({
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(paths[i]),
    stopover: false,
  });
  console.log(paths[i]);
}
console.log(waypts);
```

Comment: Have you tried, `paths.map(([lat,lng])=>({lat,lng}))`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) an array of arrays:

```js
const paths = [
  [22.372081, 114.107877],
  [22.326442, 114.167811],
  [22.284419, 114.159510]
];

let result = paths.map(([lat, lng]) => ({lat, lng}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) with alongwith [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the result.

```js
const paths = [
  [22.372081, 114.107877],
  [22.326442, 114.167811],
  [22.284419, 114.159510]
];

const waypts = paths.map(([lat, long]) => ({ lat, long }));
console.log(waypts);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is nested array, so we can flat this array using `flatMap` method:

```js
const paths = [
  [22.372081, 114.107877],
  [22.326442, 114.167811],
  [22.284419, 114.159510]
];

let result = paths.flatMap(([lat, lon]) => ({lat, lon}));
console.log(result)
```